# How can I know the line equivalence of two similar files?

Tags: diff, dynamic-programming, utility

When I add a line to the middle of a file, all following lines have their number incremented.

Is there a utility that generates the list of equivalent line numbers between two files?

The output would be something like:

```
1 1
2 2
3 4 (line added)
4 5
```

One can probably create such utility by using dynamic programming in a way similar to the diff algorithm. Seems useful, hasn't already been done?

Comment: Be a little more concrete. Do you need a library to be embedded into another framework (which technology?) or just a tool to view it (Some diff tool like KDiff?)?
A little naive: Merge the two files and output all lines which occur more than once.

Comment: A single unix-like utility that output line number equivalence would be fine. In the end, I want to check if errors found by static tools in two differente file versions are the same or not, but I keep bumping in line number difference when lines are inserted or removed.

Comment: A combination of "cat" the two files into one and "uniq" the duplicate lines out might do the job.
I don't checked it, but it could work like this `cat file1 > result; cat file2 >> result; uniq -d result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it is pretty easy to do with python's difflib:

```
import difflib

def seq_equivs(s1, s2):
    equiv = []
    s = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=s1, b=s2)
    for m in s.get_matching_blocks():
        if m[2] == 0:
            break
        for n in range(1, 1+m[2]):
            equiv.append((m[0]+n, m[1]+n))
    return equiv
```

Example usage:

```
f1 = open('file1.txt').read().split('\n')
f2 = open('file2.txt').read().split('\n')

for equivs in seq_equivs(f1, f2):
    print('%d %d' % equivs)
```